# What is `classForCoder()`?

Tags: swift

Apple was a little sparse on the explanation for [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth/iobluetoothsdpuuid/1431004-classforcoder).

I am seeing it used, but I have no idea what it is or what its for.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1411876-classforcoder

Comment: @Alexander, even that is confusing.  What exactly do they mean by "during coding?" When else would it apply? Does that really just mean not useful for production per se? Its really confusing for me.  What does it mean to "substitute a class other than its own?".

Comment: They don’t mean “coding” as a verb meaning “to program”. They referring to NSCoding, as the discussion says: “ This method is invoked by NSCoder”. There’s a documentation page on that: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding . Read more up on NSCoding, and lmk if you still have questions

Comment: Ah got it.  Thank you!